# Set NSButton size in NSStackView

Tags: swift, cocoa

I programmatically create buttons using this code

```
 let button: NSButton = NSButton()
 button.action = #selector(ViewController.eject)
 button.bezelStyle = .texturedSquare                              
 buttons.append(button)
 stackView.addView(buttons[i], in: .leading)
```

The problem is that those buttons appear like that
[image]

I would like to set the (x , y) position and the size of those buttons. For example, I would like to set their width to fill the whole space.
I tried multiple solutions:

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0.0,width: 100.0,height: 100.0)
```

and play with the arguments, but still their size don't change.
I then tried to add them as `SubViews` to `stackView`, but obviously they overlap with each other.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

To fix those buttons you first have to modify the StackView element in the storyboard.
Go to the menu of the storyboard and modify it like that
[image]

With the "fill" distribution you let the buttons to fill the entire width of the stackview.
With "spacing" you define how much space there has to be between each button.

Then you go there

[image]

To give some space to the buttons just play with the Edge Insets values.
Then set the horizontal Hugging Propriety to 250.

The last thing you have to do is to add this code in your ViewController file.

```
button.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority.init(1), for: .horizontal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

In this way you'll the the horizontal Hugging Propriety of the button to 1.
Here's the buttons I created

[image]